# emacs: Evaluate buffer contents as an s-expression?

Tags: emacs, buffer, eval, s-expression

Suppose I have an emacs buffer which contains the following text:

```
'(1 2 3)
```

I would like to evaluate the contents of this buffer as a lisp exprerssion (an s-expression). If I invoke **(eval (buffer-string))**, the result simply gets evaluated as the following string:

```
"'(1 2 3)"
```

I want the result to be evaluated as a lisp statement. In this example, I want the result to be a 3-element list, not a string.

I haven't figured out how to do this. Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>You can use `(eval-buffer)` to evaluate the entire buffer.</del> <sub>`eval-buffer` is not the solution to this, because it always returns `nil`.</sub>

If you want to go through a string, you can use `read-from-string`.  Since that returns both what it parsed and the index where it stopped parsing, as a cons cell, you usually want to call `car` on its return value:

```
(eval (car (read-from-string (buffer-string))))
```

Comment: (eval-buffer) returns nil, so I can't use it to return the value of the expression in the buffer. However, (eval (car (read-from-string (buffer-string)))) indeed works. I forgot about read-from-string. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, should have tested that before answering :)